Calculating limit of $f'$ without continuity

$f$ is a differentiable function with $f'(1)=4, f'(2)=6$, then find the value of $\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{f\left(2+2h+h^2\right)-f(2)}{f\left(1+h-h^2\right)-f(1)}$


The solution I saw used L'hospital to get that the given limit is equal to $\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{f'\left(2+2h+h^2\right)(2h+2)}{f\left(1+h-h^2\right)(-2h+1)}$ which they equated directly to $\frac{2f'(2)}{f'(1)}$, but my question is, how do we know $\lim_{h\rightarrow 0} f'(2+2h+h^2)=f'(2)$ when we don't know whether $f'(x)$ is continuous or not?

Agreed, they should not have used l'Hopital. What they shoud have done was simply re-write it as $$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\frac{f(2+2h+h^2)-f(2)}{2h+h^2}}{\frac{f(1+h-h^2)-f(1)}{h-h^2}}\frac{2h+h^2}{h-h^2}=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\frac{f(2+2h+h^2)-f(2)}{2h+h^2}}{\frac{f(1+h-h^2)-f(1)}{h-h^2}}\cdot\frac{2+h}{1-h}=\frac{f'(2)}{f'(1)}\cdot2$$ The latter just follows by quotient of limits (each term of the first fraction converges to the derivative by substitution, since $h\mapsto 2h+h^2$ and $h\mapsto h-h^2$ are injective and continuous in some neighbourhood of $0$).

When a function is differentiable at a point $x=x_0$, its $1$st-order derivative is continuous at $x=x_0$, otherwise, the left and right derivatives are not equal (if they exist).

@MostafaAyaz No, it needn't be, see for instance $x_0=0$ and $f(x)=\begin{cases}0&\text{if }x=0\ x+x^2\sin(x^{-1})&\text{if }x\ne 0\end{cases}$, which has derivative $f'(x)=\begin{cases} 1&\text{if }x=0\ 1+2x\sin(x^{-1})-\cos(x^{-1})&\text{if }x\ne 0\end{cases}$.

@SassatelliGiulio, you're right. My naive mistake :(

Using Peano's form for the remainder in taylor's theorem,
$$ f(2+2h+h^2) = f(2)+f'(2)h(2+h)+g_1(h)h(2+h), \quad \lim_{h\to 0} g_1(h)=0,$$
$$ f(1+h-h^2) = f(1)+f'(1)h(1-h)+g_2(h)h(1-h), \quad \lim_{h\to 0} g_2(h)=0,$$
Thus, the limit is $$ \lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f(2+2h+h^2) - f(2)}{f(1+h-h^2)-f(1)} = \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{2+h}{1-h}\frac{f'(2)+g_2(h)}{f'(1)+g_2(h)} = 2\frac{f'(2)}{f'(1)} = 3. $$
